# CakePHP 3 - FriendsOfCake Search Plugin - Convert date format before data is compared

Tags: php, mysql, search, cakephp-3.0

Plugin:  `FriendsOfCake/Search`

```
CakePHP Version: 1.3.4
```

I use the search plugin to filter data with a form in a view. In the database, fields of type DATE have the format **YYYY-mm-dd** but in the input field on the page the data needs to be inserted like **dd.mm.YYYY** by the user.

So I need to convert the date inserted in the form field to the format used in the database before values are compared.

What I don't get is *where* to actually "grab" the value to do the convertion within the plugins setup. I tried some things in the controller to either convert "return_ticket" or "opening_date" before they are compared with each other but I can't figure out anything that's working. Can someone help me with this?

**At which point could I do the date/string convertion in the following setup?**

```php
// plugin settings in table
class TicketsTable extends Table
{
    public function searchConfiguration()
    {
    $search = new Manager($this);

    $search->value('ticket_return',[
            'field' => $this->Appointments->target()->aliasField('opening_date')
    ]);

    return $search;
}
```

```php
// search setup in controller

class TicketsController extends AppController
{
    public function index()
    {
    $query = $this->Tickets
        ->find('search', 
            $this->Tickets->filterParams($this->request->query))
    }
}
```

```php
// search form in view
<?= $this->Form->input(
                  'ticket_return', [
                     'label' => 'search date'
                     'default' => $this_date   // today
                  ]) 
?>
```